# substract two strings in dplyr row wise for R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Have two columns and need a third substracting the two using dplyr.
Very simple example for the sake of clarity. Split/separate approach not valid in my case.

```
 x <- c("FRANCE","GERMANY","RUSSIA")
 y <- c("Paris FRANCE", "Berlin GERMANY", "Moscow RUSSIA")
 cities <- data.frame(x,y)

 cities
        x              y
1  FRANCE   Paris FRANCE
2 GERMANY Berlin GERMANY
3  RUSSIA  Moscow RUSSIA
```

Expected results:

```
     x              y      new
1  FRANCE   Paris FRANCE     Paris
2 GERMANY Berlin GERMANY     Berlin
3  RUSSIA  Moscow RUSSIA     Moscow
```

What I've tried so far (to no avail):

this gets the very same df but removing the city (contrary as desired)

```
 cities %>% mutate(new = setdiff(x,y))

            x              y     new
    1  FRANCE   Paris FRANCE  FRANCE
    2 GERMANY Berlin GERMANY GERMANY
    3  RUSSIA  Moscow RUSSIA  RUSSIA
```

On the contrary, setdiff in reverse order gets same initial data

```
 cities %>% mutate(new = setdiff(y,x))

        x                y       new
    1  FRANCE   Paris   FRANCE   Paris FRANCE
    2  GERMANY Berlin   GERMANY  Berlin GERMANY
    3  RUSSIA  Moscow   RUSSIA   Moscow RUSSIA
```

Using gsub to remove worked just for first row issuing a warning

```
  cities %>% mutate(new = gsub(x,"",y))

    Warning message:
    In gsub(x, "", y) :
      argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
            x              y            new
    1  FRANCE   Paris FRANCE         Paris 
    2 GERMANY Berlin GERMANY Berlin GERMANY
    3  RUSSIA  Moscow RUSSIA  Moscow RUSSIA
```

Comment: Could do `cities %>% mutate(new = stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(y, x, ""))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `stringr::str_replace`:

```
library(tidyverse)
cities %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(new = trimws(str_replace(y, x, "")))
#        x              y    new
#1  FRANCE   Paris FRANCE  Paris
#2 GERMANY Berlin GERMANY Berlin
#3  RUSSIA  Moscow RUSSIA Moscow
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with base R:

```
x <- c("FRANCE","GERMANY","RUSSIA")
y <- c("Paris FRANCE", "Berlin GERMANY", "Moscow RUSSIA")
cities <- data.frame(x,y,stringsAsFactors = F)

cities$new = mapply(function(a,b) 
     {setdiff(strsplit(a,' ')[[1]],strsplit(b,' ')[[1]])}, cities$y, cities$x)
```

Output:

```
        x              y    new
1  FRANCE   Paris FRANCE  Paris
2 GERMANY Berlin GERMANY Berlin
3  RUSSIA  Moscow RUSSIA Moscow
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or `trimws(mapply(function(a, b) gsub(a, "", b, fixed  = TRUE), cities$x, cities$y))`

Comment: That does look cleaner :)